# WCF binding error

Tags: .net, asp.net, wcf, binding

So I got into work early today and got the latest from source control. When I try to launch our ASP.NET application, I get this exception:

"The binding at system.serviceModel/bindings/wsHttpBinding does not have a configured binding named 'wsHttpBinding_Unsecured_Long'. This is an invalid value for bindingConfiguration. (C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\machine.config line 789)"

Nobody's here at work yet so I can't get any help on this. What the heck does this mean--can someone try to briefly explain it to me, and can I fix it? (I work on the front-end side and this looks related to the WCF services we have, so I'm not familiar.)

Comment: Can you post an example of your .config file?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your IT department pushed out some changes to the machine.config file which are bad.

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem with your WCF configuration. An end point my be pointing to a binding configuration that is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Drew. You have an endpoint that is using a bindingconfiguration that does not exist.

Just wanted to add that that type of configuration does not belong in the machine config.